# CDK get a webACLId of WAF

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-waf

How to get a `webACLId` of WAF

I'm trying to create Cloudfront distribution with WAF.

I tried to create custom resource to get it, but no luck

```
new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, 'GetParameter', {
            onUpdate: { // will also be called for a CREATE event
            service: 'WAF',
            action: 'ListWebACLs',
            // parameters: {
            //     Limit: 10,
            //     NextMarker: 'cloudfrontwebacl'
            // },
            physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of('Date.now().toString()'), 
            },
            policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({
            resources: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE,
            }),
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh. The *webACLId* should be extract by using *Ref*

Example:

```
//  Create WAF Rule
const rule = new CfnRule(this,'rule',{
  metricName:'rule',
  name:'rule',
  predicates:[
    ...
  ]
})
...
//  Create WAF WebACL
const CloudfrontWebACL = new CfnWebACL(this, "cloudfrontwebacl", {
    name: "cloudfrontwebacl",
    defaultAction: { type: 'ALLOW' },
    metricName: 'cloudfrontwebacl',
    rules:[
      {
        priority: 0,
        ruleId: rule.ref,
        action:{
          type: 'BLOCK',
        }
      }
    ]
})
...
//  Create Cloudfront distribution for web
...
webAclId: CloudfrontWebACL.ref,
...
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-waf-webacl.html#aws-resource-waf-webacl-return-values

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).